# How do you iterate over a string by character

Tags: string, iterator, rust

I have a string and I need to scan for every occurrence of "foo" and read all the text following it until a second `"`. <s>Since Rust does not have a `contains` function for strings</s>, I need to iterate by characters scanning for it. How would I do this?

**Edit**: Rust's `&str` has a [`contains()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.contains) and [`find()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.find) method.

Comment: Could you show an example of some inputs with your desired outputs? It will help us see more clearly what you are trying to accomplish exactly.

Comment: there's an example of such loop here http://rustbyexample.org/loops.html, although I think there're easier means for that.

Comment: Note that there are many string search algorithms, and their time complexity is not that of a straightforward approach (`O(n*m)`). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: This sounds like regex.

Answer (score 240):

> I need to iterate by characters scanning for it.

The [`.chars()` method](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) returns an iterator over characters in a string. e.g.

```
for c in my_str.chars() { 
    // do something with `c`
}

for (i, c) in my_str.chars().enumerate() {
    // do something with character `c` and index `i`
}
```

If you are interested in the byte offsets of each char, you can use [`char_indices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices).

Look into `.peekable()`, and use `peek()` for looking ahead. It's wrapped like this because it supports UTF-8 codepoints instead of being a simple vector of characters.

You could also create a vector of `char`s and work on it from there, but that's more time and space intensive:

```
let my_chars: Vec<_> = mystr.chars().collect();
```

Comment: Beware that the characters obtained this way might not correspond to an intuitive definition of a character as perceived by humans. See https://github.com/unicode-rs/unicode-segmentation for more details.

Comment: Does this destroy/consume the string?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant: No, as the signature of the method shows, it takes an immutable reference to `self`, not `self` itself or a mutable reference to it. It iterates the underlying data directly, without changing it in any way.

Answer (score 31):

The concept of a "character" is very ambiguous and can mean many different things depending on the type of data you are working with. The most obvious answer is the [`chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) method. However, this does not work as advertised. What looks like a single "character" to you may actually be made up of multiple Unicode *code points*, which can lead to unexpected results:

```rust
"a̐".chars() // => ['a', '\u{310}']
```

For a lot of string processing, you want to work with *graphemes*. A grapheme consists of one or more unicode code points represented as a string slice. These map better to the human perception of "characters". To create an iterator of graphemes, you can use the [`unicode-segmentation`](https://github.com/unicode-rs/unicode-segmentation) crate:

```rust
use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation;

for grapheme in my_str.graphemes(true) {
    // ...
}
```

If you are working with raw ASCII then none of the above applies to you, and you can simply use the `bytes` iterator:

```rust
for byte in my_str.bytes() {
    // ...
}
```

Although, if you are working with ASCII then arguably you shouldn't be using `String`/`&str` at all and instead use `Vec<u8>`/`&[u8]` directly.

Comment: Interesting last sentence statement. Any pointers to why String is not advised for simple ASCII? I'm learning Rust.

Comment: @DawidLaszuk A String cannot be indexed directly, and has to perform extra utf8 checks to be manipulated. It's easier, and less overhead to work with bytes directly.

Answer (score 6):

```
fn main() {
let s = "Rust is a programming language";
for i in s.chars() {
    print!("{}", i);
}}
```

> Output: Rust is a programming language

I use the chars() method to iterate over each element of the string.

Comment: Sorry, but what does this add to the accepted answer?