# How do I borrow an Iterator?

Tags: rust

I have a piece of code that I'm using that I found [in another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542115/how-to-index-a-string-in-rust)

```
fn is_palindromic(num: i64) -> bool {
    let string = num.to_string();
    let bytes = string.as_bytes();
    let iter = bytes.iter();
    let n = bytes.len() / 2;
    equals(iter.take(n), iter.rev().take(n))
}
```

This worked fine when I originally found it, but something changed in the Rust nightlies between 1/30/15 and 2/17/12 that caused this new error to pop up:

```
src/program.rs:8:26: 8:30 error: use of moved value: `iter`
src/program.rs:8     equals(iter.take(n), iter.rev().take(n))
                                          ^~~~
src/program.rs:8:12: 8:16 note: `iter` moved here because it has type `core::slice::Iter<'_, u8>`, which is non-copyable
src/program.rs:8     equals(iter.take(n), iter.rev().take(n))
                            ^~~~
```

I've looked through the documentation, but I can't seem to find anything that indicates what might have changed. It seems like maybe the `take` method now behaves differently, but I'm not really sure how to solve the situation short of cloning `bytes` and using two separate iterators.

This seems like a really inefficient way of solving what seems like a pretty common problem, so I'm thinking I may be missing something.

**What is the correct method of borrowing an iterator for use with methods like `std::iter::order::equals`?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to clone the underlying data (`bytes`), but you do need to clone the iterator:

```
fn is_palindromic(num: i64) -> bool {
    let string = num.to_string();
    let bytes = string.as_bytes();
    let iter = bytes.iter();
    let n = bytes.len() / 2;
    equals(iter.clone().take(n), iter.rev().take(n))
}
```

The iterator isn't implicitly [`Copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html)-able, so you need to explicitly [`Clone`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) it.

This changed in [this commit](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/ed82b5a70e0ddeea284addef7762375ae5880672), when [`IntoIterator` was introduced](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/20790):

> This PR also makes iterator non-implicitly copyable, as this was source of subtle bugs in the libraries. You can still use clone() to explictly copy the iterator.

See also:

- [How do I compare a vector against a reversed version of itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33348032/155423)

Comment: Awesome, this turned out to be a pretty simple solution. Do you have any idea what changed in Rust recently that makes this necessary?

Comment: @TwentyMiles Updated with that info.