# How do I compare a vector against a reversed version of itself?

Tags: rust, equality

Why won't this compile?

```
fn isPalindrome<T>(v: Vec<T>) -> bool {
  return v.reverse() == v;
}
```

I get

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:2:25
  |
2 |   return v.reverse() == v;
  |                         ^ expected (), found struct `std::vec::Vec`
  |
  = note: expected type `()`
             found type `std::vec::Vec<T>`
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Read up on [the documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.reverse) for the function you are using:

> Reverse the order of elements in a slice, in place.

Or check the function signature:

```
fn reverse(&mut self)
```

The return value of the method is the unit type, an empty tuple `()`. You can't compare that against a vector.

---

Stylistically, Rust uses 4 space indents, `snake_case` identifiers for functions and variables, and has an implicit return at the end of blocks. You should adjust to these conventions in a new language.

Additionally, you should [take a `&[T]` instead of a `Vec<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423) if you are not adding items to the vector.

To solve your problem, we will use *iterators* to compare the slice. You can get forward and backward iterators of a slice, which requires a very small amount of space compared to reversing the entire array. [`Iterator::eq`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.eq) allows you to do the comparison succinctly.

You also need to state that the `T` is comparable against itself, which requires [`Eq`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html) or [`PartialEq`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html).

```
fn is_palindrome<T>(v: &[T]) -> bool
where
    T: Eq,
{
    v.iter().eq(v.iter().rev())
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", is_palindrome(&[1, 2, 3]));
    println!("{}", is_palindrome(&[1, 2, 1]));
}
```

If you wanted to do the less-space efficient version, you have to allocate a new vector yourself:

```
fn is_palindrome<T>(v: &[T]) -> bool
where
    T: Eq + Clone,
{
    let mut reverse = v.to_vec();
    reverse.reverse();
    reverse == v
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", is_palindrome(&[1, 2, 3]));
    println!("{}", is_palindrome(&[1, 2, 1]));
}
```

Note that we are now also required to [`Clone`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) the items in the vector, so we add that *trait bound* to the method.

Comment: You're doing double work, by looking at every element twice. I've posted an alternative answer. :)

Comment: @bluss it's true, but was closer in spirit to the code in the original question.

Answer (score 17):

Since you only need to look at the front half and back half, you can use the `DoubleEndedIterator` trait (methods `.next()` and `.next_back()`) to look at pairs of front and back elements this way:

```
/// Determine if an iterable equals itself reversed
fn is_palindrome<I>(iterable: I) -> bool
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: PartialEq,
    I::IntoIter: DoubleEndedIterator,
{
    let mut iter = iterable.into_iter();
    while let (Some(front), Some(back)) = (iter.next(), iter.next_back()) {
        if front != back {
            return false;
        }
    }

    true
}
```

[(run in playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e1f29743a8a15451484b7b5bb7563a8d&version=stable)

This version is a bit more general, since it supports any iterable that is double ended, for example slice and chars iterators.

It only examines each element once, and it automatically skips the remaining middle element if the iterator was of odd length.