# When should we use unwrap vs expect in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and trying to understand when should we use unwrap vs expect.

Here's a sample code:

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let query = args.get(1).unwrap();
    println!("query from unwrawp: {}", query);

    let query = args.get(1).expect("insufficient arguments");
    println!("query from expect: {}", query);

    //$ cargo run hello
    //OUTPUT:
    //query from expect: hello
    //query from unwrawp: hello

}
```

Only difference I observed is there's a custom panic message in expect. 
Are these two interchangeable or are there any special scenarios where we should use one over the other?

Comment: As far as I know they're interchangeable. I generally use `unwrap` in cases where the logic is 100% clear that there won't be a failure and `expect` with a message if there's a possibility of an edge case I haven't considered - or one which may be triggered by incorrect developer-written config files etc.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39478185/1889329) offers a good overview of the error modes to consider when choosing between one or the other. In a nutshell, `unwrap()` is a way of converting between a recoverable error and an unrecoverable error. On the flip side, when you're calling `expect()`, you assume to be in an unrecoverable error state already. I guess the guiding principle should be: If you cannot recover from a failed `unwrap()` call, choose `expect()` instead and have your diagnostic contain a better error message.

Comment: @IInspectable: I think you misread the answer you are linking to. Both `unwrap` and `expect` convert from recoverable to unrecoverable, the only difference is that one specifies a custom error message and the other doesn't.

Comment: @mat: I guess I mispresented my point. Both `unwrap()` and `expect()` will `panic!()`, when there's nothing to unwrap. In that, they are identical. It's the situation your code is in, that makes the difference. If your code cannot meaningfully continue without the unwrapped value, choose `expect()`. If you can respond to there not being a value, pick `unwrap()` instead, after verifying the value's existence. In that case `unwrap()` will only `panic!()` if there is an issue with your code, which transitions from being in a recoverable state to an unrecoverable state.

Comment: @IInspectable IMO, instead of introducing an `expect` function, it could've simply been named `unwrap_else_panic(&str)` . expect is sounding more like unit test assertion.

Comment: Both of those options introduce a function. The only difference is in their name. That doesn't change the fact that it was assumed there to be a need for `unwrap()` and something else. That something else was named `expect()`. The particular name isn't as important as the property of being different. That allows you to convey different semantics to a reader of your code.

Comment: @IInspectable Please post your comments as an answer. Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Rust doesn't have [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading), so there should be a way to declare "`unwrap` with a message", and that is `expect`.

1. `expect` == `unwrap` with a message
2. `expect_err` == `unwrap_err` with a message

About usage scenarios of "*unwrap vs expect*" [Rust Book (Ch 9)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) says:

> Using expect instead of unwrap and providing good error messages can convey your intent and make tracking down the source of a panic easier.
>   Because this error message starts with the text we specified... it will be easier to find where in the code this error message is coming from.

Comment: FWIW, besides function overloading, the same could be achieved with optional parameters, which Rust also doesn't have.

Answer (score 19):

[Alexander Fadeev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61302112/722553) is correct, but there's a bit more information from [Rust Book (Ch 9)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-03-to-panic-or-not-to-panic.html):

> It would also be appropriate to call `unwrap` when you have some other logic that ensures the `Result` will have an `Ok` value, but the logic isn’t something the compiler understands. You’ll still have a `Result` value that you need to handle: whatever operation you’re calling still has the possibility of failing in general, even though it’s logically impossible in your particular situation. If you can ensure by manually inspecting the code that you’ll never have an `Err` variant, it’s perfectly acceptable to call `unwrap`. Here’s an example:

```rust
use std::net::IpAddr;

let home: IpAddr = "127.0.0.1".parse().unwrap();
```

> We’re creating an `IpAddr` instance by parsing a hardcoded string. We can see that `127.0.0.1` is a valid IP address, so it’s acceptable to use `unwrap` here. However, having a hardcoded, valid string doesn’t change the return type of the `parse` method: we still get a `Result` value, and the compiler will still make us handle the `Result` as if the `Err` variant is a possibility because the compiler isn’t smart enough to see that this string is always a valid IP address. If the IP address string came from a user rather than being hardcoded into the program and therefore did have a possibility of failure, we’d definitely want to handle the `Result` in a more robust way instead.

So if you know that an error is never going to happen, but the compiler wants you to handle errors, `unwrap` is cleaner and shorter than needing to provide a custom and unnecessary error message if you used `expect`.

Comment: When you use unwrap in this manner sometimes it's not immediately clear to the reader why it is safe to unwrap. So instead of writing a comment on why an unwrap is safe you write it in the expect message. This way when a program panics its not only easier to find the source of the panic but also understand the conditions necessary for the panic to occur.

Comment: @PrancingCrabulon True, and I contemplated doing it that way too, but if you're really sure that the `unwrap` couldn't go wrong, there's no need to fill your binary with error messages that will never get reported. For that reason I try to always add a comment to `unwrap` that must be something like `//checked value above`. Never something like `// assuming caller has given the correct value`. I actually never use `expect()` (I think) as it means I'm not handling the error gracefully.