# Why getting panic in Rust program with an expect

Tags: string, parsing, rust, panic, expected-condition

Beginner Rust fan - I am getting a panic for either one of these.
I expected it from the first part, but not the second.
What am I missing?

```
fn main() {

    //let age = "4a";
    //let age2: i32 = age.trim().parse().unwrap();
    //println!("{:?}", age2);

    let age = "4a";
    let age2: i32 = age.trim().parse().expect("What was this?");
    println!("{:?}", age2);
}
```

Comment: The only difference between `.unwrap()` and `.expect()` is the ability to set a custom message. Both will panic all the same if there isn't a successful value.

Comment: @kmdreko Would you mind to post this as an actual answer, not a comment?

Answer (score 2):

From [`expect()`'s documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect):

> ###### Panics
>
> Panics if the value is an [`Err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Err), with a panic message including the passed message, and the content of the [`Err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#variant.Err).

The only difference to `unwrap()` is the customized error message.

See also: [When should we use unwrap vs expect in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61301581/when-should-we-use-unwrap-vs-expect-in-rust).