# How can I create an efficient iterator of chars from stdin with Rust?

Tags: rust, stdin, chars

Now that the [`Read::chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.chars) iterator [has been officially deprecated](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27802#issuecomment-383940293), what is the the proper way to obtain an iterator over the chars coming from a `Reader` like stdin without reading the entire stream into memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a couple others have mentioned, it is possible to copy [the deprecated implementation of `Read::chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.26.0/src/std/io/mod.rs.html#2025) for use in your own code. Whether this is truly ideal or not will depend on your use-case--for me, this proved to be good enough for now although it is likely that my application will outgrow this approach in the near-future.

To illustrate how this can be done, let's look at a concrete example:

```
use std::io::{self, Error, ErrorKind, Read};
use std::result;
use std::str;

struct MyReader<R> {
    inner: R,
}

impl<R: Read> MyReader<R> {
    fn new(inner: R) -> MyReader<R> {
        MyReader {
            inner,
        }
    }

#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyReaderError {
    NotUtf8,
    Other(Error),
}

impl<R: Read> Iterator for MyReader<R> {
    type Item = result::Result<char, MyReaderError>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<result::Result<char, MyReaderError>> {
        let first_byte = match read_one_byte(&mut self.inner)? {
            Ok(b) => b,
            Err(e) => return Some(Err(MyReaderError::Other(e))),
        };
        let width = utf8_char_width(first_byte);
        if width == 1 {
            return Some(Ok(first_byte as char));
        }
        if width == 0 {
            return Some(Err(MyReaderError::NotUtf8));
        }
        let mut buf = [first_byte, 0, 0, 0];
        {
            let mut start = 1;
            while start < width {
                match self.inner.read(&mut buf[start..width]) {
                    Ok(0) => return Some(Err(MyReaderError::NotUtf8)),
                    Ok(n) => start += n,
                    Err(ref e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::Interrupted => continue,
                    Err(e) => return Some(Err(MyReaderError::Other(e))),
                }
            }
        }
        Some(match str::from_utf8(&buf[..width]).ok() {
            Some(s) => Ok(s.chars().next().unwrap());
            None => Err(MyReaderError::NotUtf8),
        })
    }
}
```

The above code also requires `read_one_byte` and `utf8_char_width` to be implemented. Those should look something like:

```
static UTF8_CHAR_WIDTH: [u8; 256] = [
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, // 0x1F
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, // 0x3F
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, // 0x5F
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, // 0x7F
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, // 0x9F
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, // 0xBF
0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2, // 0xDF
3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3, // 0xEF
4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, // 0xFF
];

fn utf8_char_width(b: u8) -> usize {
    return UTF8_CHAR_WIDTH[b as usize] as usize;
}

fn read_one_byte(reader: &mut Read) -> Option<io::Result<u8>> {
    let mut buf = [0];
    loop {
        return match reader.read(&mut buf) {
            Ok(0) => None,
            Ok(..) => Some(Ok(buf[0])),
            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::Interrupted => continue,
            Err(e) => Some(Err(e)),
        };
    }
}
```

Now we can use the `MyReader` implementation to produce an iterator of `char`s over some reader, like [`io::stdin::Stdin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html):

```
fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut reader = MyReader::new(stdin.lock());
    for c in reader {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

The limitations of this approach are discussed at length in the [original issue thread](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27802). [One particular concern](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27802#issuecomment-327289332) worth pointing out however is that this iterator will not handle non-UTF-8 encoded streams correctly.

Answer (score 11):

[The corresponding issue for deprecation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27802#issuecomment-377537778) nicely sums up the problems with `Read::chars` and offers suggestions:

> Code that does not care about processing data incrementally can use
>   `Read::read_to_string` instead. Code that does care presumably also
>   wants to control its buffering strategy and work with `&[u8]` and
>   `&str` slices that are as large as possible, rather than one `char` at
>   a time. It should be based on the `str::from_utf8` function as well as
>   the `valid_up_to` and `error_len` methods of the
>   [`Utf8Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/str/struct.Utf8Error.html)
>   type. One tricky aspect is dealing with cases where a single `char` is
>   represented in UTF-8 by multiple bytes where those bytes happen to be
>   split across separate `read` calls / buffer chunks.
>   (`Utf8Error::error_len` returning `None` indicates that this may be
>   the case.) [The `utf-8` crate](https://crates.io/crates/utf-8) solves
>   this, but in order to be flexible provides an API that probably has
>   too much surface to be included in the standard library.
>
> Of course the above is for data that is always UTF-8. If other
>   character encoding need to be supported, consider using the
>   [`encoding_rs`](https://crates.io/crates/encoding_rs) or
>   [`encoding`](https://crates.io/crates/encoding) crate.

#### Your own iterator

The *most efficient* solution in terms of **number of I/O calls** is to read everything into a giant buffer `String` and iterate over that:

```
use std::io::{self, Read};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut s = String::new();
    stdin.lock().read_to_string(&mut s).expect("Couldn't read");
    for c in s.chars() {
        println!(">{}<", c);
    }
}
```

You can combine this with an answer from [Is there an owned version of String::chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47193584/155423):

```
use std::io::{self, Read};

fn reader_chars<R: Read>(mut rdr: R) -> io::Result<impl Iterator<Item = char>> {
    let mut s = String::new();
    rdr.read_to_string(&mut s)?;
    Ok(s.into_chars()) // from https://stackoverflow.com/q/47193584/155423
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let stdin = io::stdin();

    for c in reader_chars(stdin.lock())? {
        println!(">{}<", c);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

We now have a function that returns an iterator of `char`s for any type that implements `Read`.

Once you have this pattern, it's just a matter of deciding where to make the tradeoff of memory allocation vs I/O requests. Here's a similar idea that uses line-sized buffers:

```
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Read};

fn reader_chars<R: Read>(rdr: R) -> impl Iterator<Item = char> {
    // We use 6 bytes here to force emoji to be segmented for demo purposes
    // Pick more appropriate size for your case
    let reader = BufReader::with_capacity(6, rdr);

    reader
        .lines()
        .flat_map(|l| l) // Ignoring any errors
        .flat_map(|s| s.into_chars())  // from https://stackoverflow.com/q/47193584/155423
}

fn main() {
    // emoji are 4 bytes each
    let data = "";
    let data = data.as_bytes();

    for c in reader_chars(data) {
        println!(">{}<", c);
    }
}
```

The far extreme would be to perform one I/O request for every character. This wouldn't take much memory, but would have a lot of I/O overhead.

#### A pragmatic answer

Copy and paste the implementation of `Read::chars` into your own code. It will work as well as it used to.

See also:

- [Is there an owned version of String::chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47193584/155423)
- [How do you iterate over a string by character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22118221/155423)