# Creating word iterator from line iterator

Tags: rust, iterator, borrow-checker

I have a string iterator `lines` that I get from stdin with

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

let mut stdin = io::stdin();
let lines = stdin.lock().lines().map(|l| l.unwrap());
```

The `lines` iterator yields values of type `String`, not `&str`. I want to create an iterator that iterates over the input words instead of lines. It seems like this should be doable but my naive attempt does not work:

```
let words = lines.flat_map(|l| l.split_whitespace());
```

The compiler tells me that `l` is being dropped while still borrowed, which makes sense:

```
error[E0597]: `l` does not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:6:36
  |
6 |     let words = lines.flat_map(|l| l.split_whitespace());
  |                                    ^                  - `l` dropped here while still borrowed
  |                                    |
  |                                    borrowed value does not live long enough
7 | }
  | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

Is there some other clean way that accomplishes this?

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How can I create an efficient iterator of chars from stdin with Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50394209/155423) and/or [Is there an owned version of String::chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47193584/155423) / [How can I store a Chars iterator in the same struct as the String it is iterating on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43952104/155423), just replace `chars` with appropriate logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code, `lines` is an iterator over the lines read in from the reader you have obtained from `stdin`. As you say, it returns `String` instances, but you are not storing them anywhere.

`std::string::String::split_whitespace` is defined like this:

```
pub fn split_whitespace(&self) -> SplitWhitespace
```

So, it takes a reference to a string - it does not consume the string. It returns an iterator that yields string slices `&str` - which reference portions of the string, but don't own it.

In fact as soon as the closure you have passed to `flat_map` is done with it, no-one owns it, so it is dropped. That would leave the `&str` yielded by `words` dangling, thus the error.

One solution is to collect the lines into a vector, like this:

```
let lines: Vec<String> = stdin.lock().lines().map(|l| l.unwrap()).collect();

let words = lines.iter().flat_map(|l| l.split_whitespace());
```

The `String` instances are kept in the `Vec<String>`, which can live on so that the `&str` yielded by `words` have something to refer to.

If there were a lot of lines, and you did not want to keep them all in memory, you might prefer to do it a line at a time:

```
let lines = stdin.lock().lines().map(|l| l.unwrap());

let words = lines.flat_map(|l| {
    l.split_whitespace()
        .map(|s| s.to_owned())
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .into_iter()
});
```

Here the words of each line are collected into a `Vec`, a line at a time. The trade-off is less overall memory consumption, against the overhead of constructing a `Vec<String>` for each line, and copy each word into it.

You might have been hoping for a zero-copy implementation, which consumed the `Strings` that `lines` produces. I think that would be possible to create, by creating a `split_whitespace()` function that takes ownership of the `String` and returns an iterator that owns the string.

Comment: `std::string::String::split_whitespace` is a bit misleading, since `split_whitespace()` is in fact an inherent method on the primitive `str` type. The `&String` is converted to `&str` by a deref coercion.