# Why can I not `.iter()` a string slice?

Tags: rust

Why iterating over the string slice is not possible?

```
fn main() {
    let text = "abcd";
    for (i, c) in text.iter().enumerate() {
        // ...
    } 
}
```

gives an error

```
error[E0599]: no method named `iter` found for reference `&str` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:3:24
  |
3 |     for (i, c) in text.iter().enumerate() {
  |                        ^^^^ method not found in `&str`
```

How do I make the string slice iterable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you iterate over a string by character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118221/how-do-you-iterate-over-a-string-by-character)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no `.iter()` method defined for `str`; perhaps because it is potentially ambiguous. Even in your question, its not clear what exactly you want to iterate over, the *characters* or the *bytes*.

- [`.bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.bytes) will yield the raw utf-8 encoded bytes
- [`.chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) will yield the `char`s, which are unicode scalar values
- or maybe [`.graphemes()`](https://docs.rs/unicode-segmentation/1.8.0/unicode_segmentation/trait.UnicodeSegmentation.html#tymethod.graphemes) from the `unicode-segmentation` crate which yields substrings for each "user-perceived character"

There are plenty of use-cases for each, just choose which is most appropriate. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=31c5e16ad61e09d66bd0b560b5ae761d)

```
use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation; // 1.8.0

fn main() {
    let text = "‍♂️"; // browser rendering may vary
    println!("{}", text.bytes().count());         // 17
    println!("{}", text.chars().count());         // 5
    println!("{}", text.graphemes(true).count()); // 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate on a string chars, you can use the `chars()` method:

```
fn main() {
    let text = "abcd";
    for (i, c) in text.chars().enumerate() {
       println!("i={} c={}", i, c) 
    } 
}
```